# Save number as instant messanger in Addressbook iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, whatsapp, addressbook

There is an option in default address book in iPhone which shows a section with title “**Instant message (found in whatsApp)**” as shown in attached image, and when we tap on that section it will redirect to a detail screen as per attached image.(Attached image shows this section for whatsapp, which redirects to it’s “Review”(detail) screen)

I’m using bellow stated code to display that section in default address book, if that contact using my app. With the help of this link: [How to handle instant messaging URL from Contacts application (like Facebook)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21437269/how-to-handle-instant-messaging-url-from-contacts-application-like-facebook)

```
[![ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, &error);
ABRecordRef result = ABPersonCreate();

ABMultiValueRef social = ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABMultiDictionaryPropertyType);
ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(social, (__bridge CFTypeRef)(\[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"your app service name", kABPersonSocialProfileServiceKey,                                                               @"+91xxxxxxxxxx”,kABPersonSocialProfileUsernameKey, @"TestAddressBook://myVC", kABPersonSocialProfileURLKey,nil\]), (__bridge CFStringRef)@"your app special identifier", NULL);
ABRecordSetValue(result, kABPersonSocialProfileProperty, social, NULL);]
```

Now, my question is how to redirect to detail screen when user tap on that section.

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]